# Animacion de escritura de texto dinamico que identifique cuando debe saltar de linea o si se acabo el espacio de escritura?

Tags: c#, algoritmos, wpf

Tengo un animacion que escribe lineas de texto en una caja de texto, pero cuando llega al final de la caja de texto las palabras brican a la siguiente linea a mitad de la animacion.

Lo que quiero lograr es que la palabra brinque al siguiente renglon antes de empezar a escribirse sobre la caja de texto si no cabe en el espacio restante.

El proceso que estoy usando para esa animacion es simplemente un timer que va colocando el siguiente character de la posicion de la cadena.

El Segundo requerimiento es que la animacion identifique si la siguiente palabra a escribir cabe en el area visible de la caja de texto (sin producer una scroll bar) y se detenga de no ser asi.

esto lo estoy haciendo en c# en WPF

Comment: A esta pregunta le falta información importante: ¿Cómo estás haciendo la animación? ¿cuál es tu código? Tal y como está redactada es bastante amplia y sólo te vamos a poder ofrecer respuestas genéricas que pueden no solucionar tu problema concreto. Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] para más información.

Comment: hola alvaro, enrealidad una respuesta generica como "las librerias de unity" me bastarian si pudieran abordar un problema como este, ya llevo bastante tiempo investigando y sigo sin creer que no hayan creado ya un control con estas capacidades

Comment: Deberias de mostrar el codigo que tienes hasta el momento, es deficil acerce una idea completa de lo que quieres sin un ejemplo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yo usaría esta estrategia:

- para calcular el ancho usar `TextRenderer.MeasureText` . `width`,
- para saber si se produciría un scrollbar chequear las diferencias en `ClientSize.Height`y `ClientSize.Width` entre el textbox y el textrenderer
- para evitar que la animación se vea rara o con saltos, hacer los cálculos con un textbox oculto o fuera del campo visible

sin código ejemplo se complica dar una implementación puntual

Comment: Gracias Alo, 
Estoy utilizando la funcion formattedText  para evitar usar cajas de texto ocultas, pero a estas alturas no se que de mas eficiencia en tiempo de ejecucion (necesito que esto sea altamente eficiente) 

estaba pensando si colocar un label escondido y cuando la longitud del label sea mayor que la de la caja de texto entonces hacer el salto de linea, el problema es que objetos escondidos no tienen dimensiones -.-

Comment: y fuera del campo visible ? como un child de un panel que es demasiado chico para que se vea el textbox y sin scrollbars (autoscroll flase en el panel), técnicamente seguiría siendo "visible"

Answer (score 1):

Despues de tanto esperar no pude encontrar un codigo que manejara esto eficientemente.

asi que tube que diseñar mi propio algoritmo

1.-calcular la longitud de la palabra
2.-añadir longitud de la palabra a la longitud total escrita en el renglon
3.-si la longitud total es menor al ancho de la caja de texto: continuar escribiendo
4.-si la longitud total es mayor al ancho de la caja de texto: saltar linea: continuar escribiendo, longtiud total = 0

Comment: para realizar esto necesitaria calcular una y otra vez la cantidad total escrita cada vez que escribo una nueva palabra. en lugar de eso es preferible llevar un conteo de lo que he escrito y asi me ahorro el calculo

Answer (score 1):

Creo que no te haría falta calcular la longitud total escrita.
1-Calculas el espacio disponible de la caja.
2-Calculas la longitud de la palabra o de lo que quieres añadir
3-Haces la diferencia y actualizas el espacio disponible y si es menor que cero no queda espacio